# How to make ngnix docker containers accessible through proxy?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

Let's say I have three docker containers with nginx. Their exposed port is mapped to 8080, 8181 and 8282 respectively. I want to configure the server on 8080 that it proxies /example01 and /example02 to the other two applications. This is my config file:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index   index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /example01 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/;
    }

    location /example02 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8282/;
    }
}
```

So if I run the containers, each of the applications are accessible (http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:8181 and http://localhost:8282).

Now, I don't really get why http://localhost:8080/example01 and http://localhost:8080/example02 are not redirecting correctly. Instead I get a 502 bad gateway error. Does it have something to do with my exposed ports and the VIRTUAL_PORT?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you try to edit config file as `proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/example01; ` and `proxy_pass http://localhost:8282/example02;` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the container network scope. Those container's `localhost`'s are inside each container respectively - and that's not where your ports are mapped to. Instead do:

```
$ ifconfig
```

on your host machine and find your local ip address and proxy the traffic to your host - that has the ports mapped.

conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index   index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /example01 {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8181/;
    }

    location /example02 {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2:8282/;
    }
}
```

where `192.168.1.2` is your own machine local ip address.

Another way would be to link those containers and not proxy via localhost - but the alias you'd provide in the link definition. I can elaborate if you choose this method.

**-- edit with the linking method --**

In order to have your services linked, you need to use a docker tool `docker-compose`. Assuming you're familiar with what it is ( doc refs on the bottom ), you could write a compose file like this:

```
first-nginx:
   build: first-nginx/
   ports:
      - 8080:80
   links:
      - second-nginx
      - third-nginx

second-nginx:
   build: second-nginx/
   ports:
      - 8081:80

third-nginx:
   build: third-nginx/
   ports:
      - 8082:80
```

Placed in your project's root directory like this:

```
root
  - first-nginx
    + nginx.conf
    + Dockerfile
    + some-other.files
  - second-nginx
    + some.files
    + another-nginx.conf
    + Dockerfile
  - third-nginx
    + some-nginx.conf
    + Dockerfile
  + docker-compose.yml
```

And you'd configure the "main" nginx to utilize the created links like so:

conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        root    /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index   index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /example01 {
        proxy_pass http://second-nginx/;
    }

    location /example02 {
        proxy_pass http://third-nginx/;
    }
}
```

Be sure to ask if anything is unclear.

[links ref](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#links)

[compose ref](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you! Would you mind elaborating on the linking of containers? I am new to this

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful. I am just learning this stuff.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Take care ;)